# Javascript policy error when processing takes over 200ms

Tags: apigee

Is there a way to allow javascript policies to process for over 200 ms, without throwing an error.

Currently seeing this with one of my policies that is parsing large amounts of json

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be solved by adding a timeLimit Attribute to the Javascript Tag

```
<Javascript async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" timeLimit="300" name="Script-ApplyTransformations">
```

Comment: You say your are parsing large JSON, will extract variables or transformation policies not work. I am assuming they are better optimized than Javascript callout.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, according to the [Apigee docs](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/programming-api-proxies-javascript#going-with-the-flow), 200ms is the upper limit for free organizations.

Comment: This is a non "Free" Org

Answer (score 1):

Just be cautious of doing too much heavy lifting of transformations with pure JS code, as it may not only impact performance but the complexity and maintenance of your API proxy. One suggestion is to have a Transformation framework in place, so you can apply consistently across your APIs and improve maintainability across your team. Another suggestion is to implement Tolerant Reader techniques http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TolerantReader.html, so the path to the data isn't hard coded. I used JSONPath on a previous project see https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/wiki/Javascript

Comment: The javascript in question is very efficient, but the javascript engine itself on its first request can cause an occasional blip, increasing this time allows that policy to take awhile on its first run

Comment: Yes agree with Diego - this 200 ms limit is an indication that we are probably doing something 'heavy' with JS policy.

Comment: I noticed that too Steve. With no apparent reason the engine goes from 30ms to over 200ms for the same request. Bumping timelimit up and keeping it monitored are probably your best bet.